# C# Multithreading sample returning same output for different accounts

Tags: c#, multithreading

See sample below, when I run this it always returns the name of first account number(111111) in the list. 
If I comment the 'Thread' part everything works fine.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> testdata = new List<int>();
    testdata.Add(111111);
    testdata.Add(222222);
    testdata.Add(333333);

    foreach (int data in testdata)
    {
        new Thread(delegate()
        {
            DataTable dt = DB.GetData(data);
            if (dt.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", dt.Rows[0]["Name"];);
            }

            // Signal the CountdownEvent.
            countdownEvent.Signal();
        }).Start();
    }

    // Wait for workers.
    countdownEvent.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Finished."); 
}
```

Current Output:

```
Name: JULIE
Name: JULIE
Name: JULIE
```

**Note**: Always returning name of ID 111111

Expected Output:

```
Name: JULIE
Name: JOHN
Name: GRANT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass data to your delegate arg like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> testdata = new List<int>();

    testdata.Add(111111);
    testdata.Add(222222);
    testdata.Add(333333);

    foreach (int data in testdata)
    {
        new Thread(delegate(object arg)
        {
            DataTable dt = DB.GetData((int) arg);
            if (dt.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", dt.Rows[0]["Name"];);
            }

            // Signal the CountdownEvent.
            countdownEvent.Signal();
        }).Start(data);
    }

    // Wait for workers.
    countdownEvent.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Finished."); 
}
```

Comment: new Thread(delegate(data) giving me "Identifier expected" error.

Comment: sorry `delegate(object arg)` instead of `delegate(arg)`

Answer (score 6):

Closure. Make a copy of the `data` variable first thing in the thread. The way you do it now, the thread will run with whatever value is in data when it runs - and likely all three run on the last data due to delays between the call to Start() and the moment the thread executes.

Comment: *Or*, if possible use the C# 5.0 compiler, which solved the *foreach-closure issue*.